# stop page from loading after dialog box opens

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

What I'm trying to do is have a contact form, and when the user hits submit a dialog box appears asking the user to confirm yes/no, and the form should not submit until the user has selected yes, or stays on the page when selects no.

What my issue is, once the dialog box opens, the form still submits, and the dialog box is open for only a second or so.

So is it possible to stop the page from loading until after the dialog box is closed or yes is clicked?

I'm using the jQuery Impromptu plugin for the dialog box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use  `type="submit"`, just use  `type="button"`. Submit the form from your own code based on the dialog result.

Comment: Excellent, That worked. Now my only issue is that the form doesn't actually submit, it pops up with the form error that the page cannot be accessed directly (located in the nlphpmail.php file)

Comment: You're not submitting the form, you're redirecting with *window.location*. Use: document.forms[0].submit.

Comment: I guess i'm not understanding how to implement that. Am I changing `window.location="nlphpmail.php";` to just `document.forms[0].submit`?

Comment: Yes. Actually: *document.forms[0].submit();*

Comment: now it does nothing but close the dialog box... not sure whats happening. can you review the source and make sure it is correct?

Comment: still can't find a resolution to this, i've tried everything, and still does nothing but close the dialog box. @Diodeus

Comment: document.form[email].submit(); is looking for a variable called "email". You don't have one. Just use "0".

Comment: even if I use "0", it still does nothing. @Diodeus

Comment: resolved, on button inputs had id=submit and name=submit, needed to be changed to something different.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the impromptu library; however, I believe that this can be done by stopping the onClick event from submitting and submitting via the callback in your go_there() method.  I would try replacing the onClick method with `"go_there(); return false;"`.  This should cancel the normal submit event.  Then you could add a submit statement (`document.email.submit();`) in the true condition of your callback before you reset the location.

Comment: this did not seem to work, or I'm not sure how to add the submit statement to the true condition

Comment: I pulled up the test page in the initial post.  It appears to be working correctly.  Is there still an issue?